# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React / JS noob here. I'm getting the following error - "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined" when trying to run the following -

```
import React from 'react';

const { Client } = require('tplink-smarthome-api');

let client = new Client()

const plug = client.getDevice({host: '192.168.1.10'}).then((device)=>{
  device.getSysInfo().then(console.log);
  device.setPowerState(true);
});
```

I've tried using async functions like --

```
const toggle = async () => {
const plug =  await client.getPlug({ host: '192.168.1.10' })
plug.setPowerState(true)
}
```

The above code works until the plug.setPowerState(true). That results in an "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined". This runs fine in node.js but as soon as I attempt to bring react into the mix, nothing. Thanks - I've been trying for days.

Comment: `destroy` is nowhere in the code you posted - can you post the code which has `destroy` in it?

Comment: Are you running on the browser or the server?

Comment: I used `npx create-react-app` to create the app. I'm running it like `npm start`. Not sure where the `destroy` is coming from.